# knockout.js updating a select list does not fire on first change

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have 2 select lists and I want to sync the index, so when the first has an index of 1 the second will have an index of 1 etc.

This is my html.

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div>
<select id="selLight" data-bind="options: $root.ddlLight, value: ddlLightSelected"></select>
<select id="selAction" data-bind="options: $root.ddlAction, value: ddlActionSelected"></select>
</div>
```

and the javascript...

```
var ViewModel = function() {
    var self = this;

    self.ddlLight  = ko.observableArray(["RED", "AMBER", "GREEN"]);
    self.ddlAction = ko.observableArray(["STOP", "READY", "GO"]);
    self.ddlLightSelected  = ko.observable();
    self.ddlActionSelected = ko.observable();

    self.ddlLightSelected.subscribe(function (event) {
        document.getElementById("selAction").selectedIndex =
            self.ddlLight.indexOf(self.ddlLightSelected());
     });

    self.ddlActionSelected.subscribe(function (event) {
        document.getElementById("selLight").selectedIndex =
            self.ddlAction.indexOf(self.ddlActionSelected());
     });    
};

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

I have a fiddle with the exact problem...

http://jsfiddle.net/phykell/2vUTw/

EDIT: I was having a few problems with jsfiddle, so here is a jsbin...
http://jsbin.com/ilomer/4/

...and here's how to recreate the issue:

1. Run the jsFiddle
2. Select GREEN from the LIGHTS (ACTIONS will change to GO) 3. Select STOP from the ACTIONS (LIGHTS should change to RED but they don't)

Comment: Was not able to try out your code, but a couple of observations 1. Your ddl*Selected observables are initialized with nulls. You might want to start them off with some base values. So that when the first .subscribe mtheod executes you dont get a null or -1 in the indexOf operation. 2. Why are you doing document.getElement.. and not updating your respective selected observable itself ?

Comment: It was my understanding that this is the way to get the selected index? If I update the "self.ddlLightSelected" for example, the value does not change for the select box.

Comment: jsfiddle is not working just now, but your example works here http://tinkerbin.com/eQo0XM1P - just select Run

Comment: Thanks Tim, the problem I have is when I have changed the first select list(for the first time), and then try and change the value in the second to "STOP", the first select box does not change.

ryadavilli: I will try your suggestion and initialize with some values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is this line of code:

```
document.getElementById("selAction").selectedIndex = self.ddlLight.indexOf(self.ddlLightSelected());
```

You're directly changing the DOM, not allowing Knockout to kick off the observable pattern.

If you want something to change, always change the `ko.observable`, not the JavaScript variable or the DOM. Knockout will recognize the change, and therefor change the DOM itself. The solution would be:

```
self.ddlLightSelected.subscribe(function (event) {
      var index = self.ddlLight.indexOf(self.ddlLightSelected());
      self.ddlActionSelected(self.ddlAction()[index]); // Update the Observable, not the DOM
});

self.ddlActionSelected.subscribe(function (event) {
    var index = self.ddlAction.indexOf(self.ddlActionSelected());
    self.ddlLightSelected(self.ddlLight()[index]); // Update the Observable, not the DOM
});
```

[**Updated JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/ilomer/5/edit).

Comment: Perfect, that has fixed the problem.